# How to compute area under the curve (intersection may occur) with the original dataset?

Tags: r, intersection, area

I have a bunch of datasets of x’s and y’s. For each dataset, I plot points (x, y) ***in R.*** And the resulting plots are generally similar to either [type A](http://imageshack.com/a/img923/9421/JG5G9e.png) or [type B](http://imageshack.com/a/img922/7793/EnsRzr.png). Type B has an intersection while type A doesn’t have.

***My question***: Given a new dataset, is it possible to calculate (***in R***) the red shaded area under the curve as indicated in type A and type B plot without knowing the visualization?

The ***main challenges*** are:

1)  How to determine whether the dataset will generate type A or type B in R?

2)  How to compute the red shaded area in type B using the dataset with R?

**Here is the code producing the dataset that generated type B curve.**

```
set.seed(300)
predicted_value_A = c(rbeta(300, 9, 2), rbeta(700, 2, 4), rbeta(10000, 2, 4))
predicted_value_B = c(rbeta(1000, 4, 3), rbeta(10000, 2, 3))
real_value = c(rep(1, 1000), rep(0, 10000))

library(ROCR)
library(ggplot2)

predB <- prediction(predicted_value_B, real_value)
perfB <- performance(predB, measure = "mat", x.measure = "f")

yB <- attr(perfB, "y.values")[[1]]

yB <- (yB + 1)/2

xB <- attr(perfB, "x.values")[[1]]  

# dataset that generates type B curve
dfB <- data.frame(X = xB, Y= yB)

ggplot(df, aes(x=X, y=Y, ymin=0, ymax=1, xmin=0, xmax=1 )) + geom_point(size =     0.2, shape = 21, fill="white")+
ggtitle("Type B curve") + 
theme(plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.5))
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Not sure how this is an R question. I don't see any sample data or R coding attempts.

Comment: I added the R code that generates type B curve!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bit of code to shade the plot from a set of (x,y) points using an approximation with small rectangles. This assumes evenly spaced x values, and enough that the rectangular approximation works well.

```
# sample dataset
x <- seq(0,2,length.out=1000)
y1 <- x
y2 <- sin(x*pi)+x

# plot
plot(x,y1,type='l',ylab='y')
lines(x,y2)

# shade the plot
## not efficient but works
dx <- x[2]-x[1]
area <- 0

# shade plot and calculate area
## uses a rectangular strip approximation
## assumes even spacing in x. Could also calculate the dx in each step if it changes
for (i in 1:(length(x))) {

  if (y1[i] < y2[i]) {
    cord.x <- c(x[i]-dx/2,x[i]-dx/2,x[i]+dx/2,x[i]+dx/2)
    cord.y <- c(y1[i],y2[i],y2[i],y1[i])
  } else {
    cord.x <- c(x[i]-dx/2,x[i]-dx/2,x[i]+dx/2,x[i]+dx/2)
    cord.y <- c(y2[i],y1[i],y1[i],y2[i])
  }

  # draw the polygons
  polygon(cord.x, cord.y, col = 'pink', border = NA)

  # sum to the area
  area <- area + abs(y2[i]-y1[i])*dx
}
area
```

[sample shaded plot by rectangular approximation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dm7Mb.png)

Comment: Hi Rob, thank you! The dataset I work with is messier than the data in the above code. The x's and y's are not ordered, and it is making the computation difficult. For example, how can I determine whether (x,y) is the higher part or the lower part of the curve? btw I added the dataset of x's and y's in the question part.

Comment: I've been trying to think of a clean solution to this and haven't been able to come up with one. You can specify particular regions where the one line is clearly the upper and the other the lower for a range of x values, but that would involve basically running the above script in a piecewise manner. You could also do it analytically, except that the data looks pretty noisy, which wouldn't make that feasible.